How can Pandas .loc take three arguments?
I am looking at someones code and this is what they wrote
from financetoolkit import Toolkit

API_KEY = "FINANCIAL_MODELING_PREP_API_KEY"

companies = Toolkit(["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOGL", "AMZN"], api_key=API_KEY, start_date="2005-01-01")
income_statement_growth = companies.get_income_statement(growth=True)
display(income_statement_growth.loc[:, "Revenue", :])

Essentially what this code does is it returns the revenue value for a couple of companies starting from 2005 until present day.
What I am confused about is income_statement_growth.loc[:, "Revenue", :]
why is there three arguments? I dont understand what the third colon is doing in this code
All the documentation I read about .loc states that it takes two arguments, one for the row and one for the column, so I am a bit confused how it is able to take three and what the function of the third colon is.

What is the type of income_statement_growth? (it appears you are using financetoolkit, but you should make that explicit in the question)

I'm unfamiliar with this package. Can you [edit] your question to include your imports, etc.? It would also be nice if you linked some documentation.

@ewokx Please don't just add code fences to a post. The edit broke the indentation.

The return value of companies.get_income_statement(growth=True) is a pandas DataFrame with a multi-index. The columns are indexed by period ('2019', '2020', etc.) and the rows are indexed by a combination of company ticker and data item (e.g. ('AAPT', 'Revenue')).
You could access a single element like this:
print(income_statement_growth['2020'][('AAPL', 'Revenue')])

And to select the 'Revenue' for all tickers and all periods, you use .loc:
revenues = income_statement_growth.loc[:, 'Revenue', :]

For a simple dataframe, you world normally see two arguments for .loc[] but since this is a multi-index, this needs three arguments.

Thank you Grismar for explaining that this data frame was multi-index! That makes a lot of sense now why it written like that.

"You could access a single element like this:" - Why not use .at? income_statement_growth.at[('AAPL', 'Revenue'), '2020']

Where is this documented? I wasn't aware of this; the closest thing I knew was IndexSlice, like this: idx = pd.IndexSlice; income_statement_growth.loc[idx[:, 'Revenue'], :]

I just remembered the equivalent way I already knew: income_statement_growth.xs('Revenue', level=1)

@Grismar, are you sure the dataframe's index in the question has only two levels? Where did you get that info?

@Bill, I modified OP's code with an import statement, obtained a free API key, and ran the code.

@wjandrea one could certainly use .at (and probably would) I just wanted to show a very basic example of accessing an element with basic indices only, no fancy methods, and .at might seem as magical as .loc

@Grismar thanks. In that case I think the original code statement with three indexers is a mistake. You can't index two levels of the index and the column index in that way. Try .loc[:, 'Revenue', '2019']. I suspect it will raise an IndexError "list index out of range"

Is the index of income_statement_growth a MultiIndex?  If so, how many levels does it have? If it has three then this code is valid:
income_statement_growth.loc[:, "Revenue", :]

This selects all rows with "Revenue" in the second level of the index.
However, note that in the docs it says

this shorthand notation can lead to ambiguity in general.

So presumably it is not advisable to use it.
In this case, I would use the following instead, as @wjandrea recommended in a comment to one of the other answers:
idx = pd.IndexSlice
income_statement_growth.loc[idx[:, "Revenue", :]]

This makes it clear that you are indexing in the rows only (not in the columns as well).
Sometimes Pandas is a bit too permissive in my opinion.
Update
If the index of income_statement_growth has only two levels then I don't understand why the original author of this code used .loc[:, "Revenue", :]. That should only be used for indexing a dataframe with an index having 3 levels. It seems that Pandas simply ignores any additional : indexers so the third one is redundant in this case.
